# Embedding matplotlib moving chart in django template

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I am new to python Django framework.

I have **matplotlib** moving or live chart, It should be   **embedded  in django template**. I checked many question relevant to this  here  but none of them is worked for me. Most of us suggested here is displaying as image, but problem is **moving chart with default interface like zoom, drag** everything to be integrated. 
i am struggling to solve . I used this code and got to know it will be displaying as image.

```
def simple(request):
    import random
    import django
    import datetime

    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    x = []
    y = []
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    for i in range(10):
        x.append(now)
        now += delta
        y.append(random.randint(0, 1000))
    ax.plot_date(x, y, '-')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    response = django.http.HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

I used this code for reference.

**if this is not understandable please comment below, ill try to convey you clearly**

can any one help me to get fixed this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A png image is an image, not an application which would allow to interact with. It is therefore pretty unclear what you are asking for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing with matplotlib you can try with BOKEH chart. check this out [Bokeh charts doc](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide.html)

Answer (score 1):

While it may seem like a simple question, the machinery that matplotlib employs to present an interactive chart on desktop is reasonably complex, and not something one can just drop in to some HTML somewhere.

I would suggest you look at a frontend library for graphically displaying data, then provide your frontend the data with your backend.

As for libraries, check out [C3](http://c3js.org/).  It's got good docs and examples.

Comment: Is it possible to do with matplotlib?

Comment: Matplotlib is a _desktop_ graphing solution.  You are not targeting desktop users, you are targeting web users.  As such, you must use an in-browser, javascript, solution.

Comment: Yeah!!! Thanks ... do u have any suggestion for me to choose good open source JS for this(live forex chart)..